# How to inherit classes with arguments in coffescript?

Tags: class, inheritance, coffeescript

I have class `Human` and I want class `SocialBeing` to inherit from `Human`. But in `super(Human)` method the `Human` class is passed to `Human` class instance as the first positional argument and that's couses and error. What is the correct way to inherit `SocialBeing` from `Human`?

```
class Human  # As biological creature
    constructor: (@given_sex = null,
                  @age = null,  # Age of the person
                  @max_age = 85) ->  # Maximum allowed age of the person during person generation

        _alive = true

        alive: ->
            @_alive

        dead: ->
            not @alive()

        has_died: ->
            @_alive = false

        _available_sexes: {0: 'female', 1: 'male'}

        sex: ->
            _sex = @_available_sexes[@given_sex]

        @generate_human()

     generate_human: ->
            @_alive = true
            if @age is null
                @age = Math.floor(Math.random() * @max_age)
            if @given_sex is null
                @given_sex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
            else if @given_sex not in [0,1]
                n = @given_sex
                err = 'Invalid sex value: ' + n
                console.log(err)
                throw new Error(err)


class SocialBeing extends Human  # Describes socialisation
    constructor: (@first_name = null,
                  @second_name = null,
                  @middle_name = null,
                  @other_name = null) ->
         super(Human)

         marital_status: null

h = new SocialBeing(first_name='Pal')  # In JavaScript thows an error
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `super` in a wrong way. 
I have condensed your example a bit

```
class Human
     constructor: (@given_sex = null) ->  
          @generate_human()

     generate_human: ->
         if @given_sex is null
             @given_sex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
         else if @given_sex not in [0,1]
             n = @given_sex
             err = 'Invalid sex value: ' + n
             console.log(err)
         else
              console.log("my sex is", @given_sex)
```

Your base class is OK so far. Now for your derived class you can either set the param explicitly while calling `super`

```
class SocialBeing extends Human
     constructor: (@first_name = null) ->
          super 1
          #or
          super null
```

But somehow this defeats the purpose of your base classes constructor arguments. The usual way would be to also add the base class constructors arguments to your derived class constructors arguments

```
class SocialBeing extends Human
     constructor: (sex = null, @first_name = null) ->
          super sex
```

and then instatiate your derived class accordingly

```
h = new SocialBeing(sex = 1, first_name='Pal')
```

and while were at it descriptive constants would be nice as well

```
male = 0
female = 1
h = new SocialBeing(male, 'Pal')
```

or add any of FB's 58 gender expressions if you feel particular progressive ;-)

now obviously it can become a bit cumbersome to pipe all these ctor arguments into super. so what you can do then is

```
class Human
      constructor: (@given_sex = null,
                    @age = null,  # Age of the person
                    @max_age = 85)

class SocialBeing extends Human
     constructor: (@first_name = null,
                   @second_name = null,
                   @middle_name = null,
                   @other_name = null) ->
          super arguments...
```

However having so many arguments specifically optional ones I would regard as a design smell.

I hope this helps